# Xamarin Forms PCL - Navbar Title wont update dynamically

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have made an app with a partial CarouselLayout.

In the layout when contentChanged I'm send a message with MessageCenter

```
      MessagingCenter.Send<CarouselLayout, string>(this, "ContentChanged", "123");
```

And in my RootPage I'm listening for it, and then i want to update the title:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CarouselLayout, string>(this, "ContentChanged", (sender, arg) =>
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("ContentChanged rootpage subscribe");
    UpdateDateTitle();
  });

public void UpdateDateTitle()
{
  this.Title  = _viewModel.CurrentPage.RegList.First().DateTime.ToString("D");
}
```

I can see on the debug output and the Title, that it is updated with the new date. However the actual navigationbar title is never updated.

But it is set on initial load.

What am i getting wrong?

Comment: Have you tried on multiple platforms? What type is your `RootPage`? It should work because James Montemagno seems to have done it without a sweat in the [Evolve app](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve/blob/master/src/XamarinEvolve.Clients.UI/Pages/Speakers/SpeakerDetailsPage.xaml.cs)

Comment: I implemented it with Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread and its working, is that bad practice? - my rootpage is a ContentPage

Comment: Ah good! That isn't bad practice. If you want to update something in the UI from another thread that is the way to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed and discovered by yourself you should invoke this by using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

The MessagingCenter will use another thread and can't update the UI so you have to wrap put it on the UI thread.

It will look like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CarouselLayout, string>(this, "ContentChanged", (sender, arg) =>
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
      Debug.WriteLine("ContentChanged rootpage subscribe");
      UpdateDateTitle();
   });
});
```

Read up on what it does exactly [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/#Device_BeginInvokeOnMainThread).

Comment: Exactly, I'll accept even though I beat you to it :) Thanks for confirming

Comment: Ha thanks! Wasn't my intention, just thought I'd complete it for archiving purposes